# How to determine the source (views/modules/blocks, etc) of content in different URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

I am working on re-designing an existing site for which I need to edit the output of each page (i.e. each URL). Is there a good way to determine where the data is coming from? By "where" I mean, is it a 'View'? or from a module? or combination of blocks?

I have tried devel & theme developer but that only tells me which tpl.php file but not the actual source.

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/control-your-drupal-page-layout-context-and-delta

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable looking through your database directly, the quickest way to find out where `$content` is coming from is to look at the `menu_router` table and reference the `path` and `page_callback` fields.  For example, path `node` is generated (normally) by `node_page_default` and it creates the default front page.  Looking through this table you can see where all the other paths on your system are referenced.

As for where all the other content comes from, eg, all the blocks in other regions of the page, there you have to look around through the `blocks` table and look at the various information there, eg, `module` and `delta` say which module creates the block and which one it is, `region` says where on the page it will be put, and `pages` have any restrictions as to what pages the core block module knows about.